# How to read a file and store words to a list in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to store all the words present in a txt file, except punctuations and digits, to a list?

I'm very new to scala and can't figure out how to do it? Can anybody help?

EDIT:

I'm doing it this way right now:

```
for(line <- Source.fromFile("src/stop_words.txt").getLines())
      {
      //println(line)
      lst = line

      }
      println(lst)
```

It's giving me a redline on lst=line and says reassignment to a val. I don't know why :(

Comment: Take a a look at `scala.io.Source.fromFile(...)`. Then filter the contents for punctuation and digits.

Comment: @Brian could you see the EDIT in my question. I'm having some problem with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that each line can have multiple words a better solution would be

```
val words = """([A-Za-z])+""".r
val all = io.Source.fromFile("path/to/file.txt").getLines.flatMap(words.findAllIn).toList
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use scala.io.Source with filter by regex and toList at the end

```
io.Source.fromFile("path/to/file.txt").
  getLines().
  filter(_.matches("[A-Za-z]+")).
  toList
```

***Update***:

What's inside your file? This simple code works as expected

```
val list = io.Source.fromBytes(
    """aaa
      |bbb
      |123
      |.-ddg
      |AZvb
    """.stripMargin.toArray.map(_.toByte)).
    getLines().
    filter(_.matches("[A-Za-z]+")).
    toList

  println(list)
```

Output:

```
List(aaa, bbb, AZvb)
```

Comment: Hi, when I do var fillist = io.Source.fromFile("/Users/xyz/Desktop/file1.txt").
   getLines().
   filter(_.matches("[A-Za-z]+")).
   toList
  println(fillist)

I get an empty list as the output, why is that?

Comment: see my update, it's hard to say without content of the file, it should work, or you need to update regular expression to match

Comment: How would your first example work with `scala.utils.Using`, so that I can ensure the file is properly closed?